# Extract Data from a cell using different delimiters

Tags: excel, vba, text

I want to extract the following text from the block of text that is included at the end of this post

the extracted text strings are to be placed in separate worksheet cells

side note: the block of text is stored in a single worksheet cell

```
10/15/2017 02:57:11 AM
FirstName LastName
Closed

10/15/2017 02:56:04 AM
ZFirst ZLast
Assigned
```

.......

FYI..... The text I want to extract is between asterisks, but the asterisks are not included in the actual text string.

=========================================

```
"**10/15/2017 02:57:11 AM FirstName LastName**
     Changed Status to: **Closed**

     Changed Restoration Category to: Software

     Changed Configured Item Type to: Application

     Changed Configured Item Category to: Software

**10/15/2017 02:56:04 AM ZFirst ZLast**
     Changed Status to: **Assigned**

10/13/2017 05:21:35 AM YFirst YLast
     Changed Status to: Suspend

     Changed Date/Time Suspend Ends to: 10/18/17 13:30:00

     Changed Suspend Reason to: Awaiting Customer Action

10/13/2017 12:03:12 AM ISAuto Prod005
     Changed Status to: Assigned

10/11/2017 04:36:11 PM XFirst XLast
     Changed Date/Time Suspend Ends to: 10/12/17 13:30:00
```

=======================================================

Comment: OK, we know what you want.  How have you tried to accomplish this, and what problem did you run into?  What rules have you decided on to describe which lines to extract?

Comment: what are the rules for the strings that you want to extract? why is `10/13/2017 05:21:35 AM YFirst YLast` not extracted?

Comment: If you want useful answers, I suggest you respond to the comments above; provide the code you have developed so far, and read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you didn't say where to store results, so I put them into A column. This subroutine must be provided with arguments from other subroutine, I hope you know how to do it.

```
Sub MySplit(sStr As String)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim V, Y

sStr = Replace(sStr, "*", "")
V = Split(sStr, Chr(10))
For i = 0 To UBound(V)
    Y = Split(V(i), " ")
    For j = 0 To UBound(Y)
        Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Y(j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Not very elegant solution, but should be workable.

Comment: Actual string don't have *symbol. I need to fetch date, name of person and remaining text in any row/column. Also, this string contains many such results....